# My javaScript function is not being called at the right time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so what I was origionally doing was adding a class to my form and label for my select after the select has been changed.  That works fine.  What I want to do now is make it so that the save button only shows when the select has been changed.

```
document.getElementById('href_attr').addEventListener('change', change, false);
document.getElementById('alt_attr').addEventListener('change', change, false);
document.getElementById('title_attr').addEventListener('change', change, false);

//document.getElementById('href_attr').addEventListener('change', allChanged(), false);


function change() {
    alert('test');
    utils.addClass(form, 'changed');
    utils.addClass(this.parentNode, 'changed');
}

function allChanged(){
    utils.show(save_button);
}

document.getElementById('save_button').addEventListener('click', save, false);
```

So for some reason when I call the change function, the alert happens at the right time (when I change the select box).  When I have it call the allChanged function it is called when the page is loaded.  This is the only place that I call either function.  Also, I'm looking for a way to display the save button when ALL selects have been changed, not just one.  How can I do this? I came across jQuery's $.when     and tried:

```
$.when(href_attr.addEventListener('change'),
        alt_attr.addEventListener('change'),
    title_attr.addEventListener('change')
    ).done(allChanged());
```

and

```
$.when("#href_attr,#alt_attr,#title_attr").change(allChange());
```

with no luck.

Comment: You'd get a variable to add up values everytime a select is changed and then put the save_button display sentence between a condition that will evaluate if the variable value is enough to get the save_button to show up.

Comment: I'd use a boolean value for each element if you want each one individually to be changed before showing save and add a call a check on it at the end of change()  href_changed = true, alt_changed = true & title_changed = true;  I'll post an answer if i have time

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a callback. For example on your select input:

```
$('selector').on('change', function(event) {
    if ( $(this).val() )
    {
        // select has value so we can handle accordingly.
        updateClassNames(function(response() {
            alert('class names updated');
            $('selector:hidden').show();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // select has no value so don't do anything (or undo what we just did).
    }
});

funciton updateClassNames(callback) {
    $('selector').addClass('myClass');
    callback();
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, everything is working fine for the change function, it just breaks when I try to call a different function...why would I change to this? Can you explain what you are saying here?

Comment: Sure. IMO, this is a lot easier/cleaner to read. I'm binding a function to the change event of your select input. If there is a value (meaning something was selected) I am calling the "updateClassNames" function.

When that function runs, the last thing I do is make a callback to the function that called it - in essence telling it that I'm done. Very similar to how @ArrayKnight is suggesting. Only I am not using a promise.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.when accepts deferreds/promises and static objects. So to go about doing what you're intending, you'll need to create promises that are affected by the change event:

```
function change(node) {
    alert('test');
    utils.addClass(form, 'changed');
    utils.addClass(node.parentNode, 'changed');
}

function allChanged(){
    utils.show(save_button);
}

$.when(
    $.Deferred(function(defer) {
        href_attr.addEventListener('change', function() {
            change(href_attr);

            defer.resolve();
        })
    }),
    $.Deferred(function(defer) {
        alt_attr.addEventListener('change', function() {
            change(alt_attr);

            defer.resolve();
        })
    }),
    $.Deferred(function(defer) {
        title_attr.addEventListener('change', function() {
            change(title_attr);

            defer.resolve();
        })
    })
).done(allChanged);

document.getElementById('save_button').addEventListener('click', save, false);
```

This implementation also means that you will no longer require the first three bindings to the change event.

References: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ , http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/

Comment: When I tried to do this, it stopped adding the class to this.parentNode, only adds it to form, also the save_button is never displayed.

Comment: Weird.  So if I take the parenthases away from the call to change(), allChanged works after all have been changed.  When I add parenthases to allChanged, allChanged is called when the page loads, but not when all selects have been changed

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't pay close enough attention. You are correct, `allChanged` should not have the (). And the scope of `this` in `change` would have been changed, so we can simply pass the desired node. See updates above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty stab at this, I can do better in a couple hours although someone will probably beat me to it.

```
document.getElementById('href_attr').addEventListener('change', change, false);
document.getElementById('alt_attr').addEventListener('change', change, false);
document.getElementById('title_attr').addEventListener('change', change, false);

var href = false;
var alt = false;
var title = false;

function change() {
    alert('test');
    utils.addClass(form, 'changed');
    utils.addClass(this.parentNode, 'changed');

    switch(this.id) {
        case "href_attr"
            href = true;
            break;
        case "alt_attr"
            alt = true;
            break;
        case "title_attr"
            title = true;
            break;
    } 

    checkChanged();
}

function checkChanged() {
    if ((href) && (alt) && (title)) {
        utils.show(save_button);
    }
}

document.getElementById('save_button').addEventListener('click', save, false);
```

That should do the job (or something like it), also no jquery here.